# Distritubed algorithms video lectures

Tags: algorithm, distributed

I am looking for video lectures on distributed algorithms. Would appreciate if anyone knows of a good resource.

Regards, 
Abdul

Comment: Not videos but could be helpful: http://disco.ethz.ch/lectures/podc_allstars/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may also be that you'll have luck searching for parallel algorithms instead of distributed algorithms - I think there's quite a bit of overlap between the material covered by the two terms.

It may not have videos, but you could try MIT's OpenCourseWare on distributed algorithms [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-852j-distributed-algorithms-fall-2009/index.htm).

Cousera has a [module on heterogeneous parallel algorithms](https://www.coursera.org/course/hetero).

There are some video lectures on parallel algorithms [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-thirteen/).